# Why do these quotation marks result in text inconsistencies according to Grammarly?

Tags: quotation-marks

I submitted my writing to Grammarly and apparently the quotation marks result in text inconsistencies. Can anyone point out the error with my quotation marks? Apparently all three pairs are problematic.

> Whenever I visited Korea, people asked, "Are you more comfortable speaking Korean or English?" After surprising me with a question supposed to be easier than it seemed, they continued by asking, "Do you prefer living in Korea or Canada? Which culture do you like better?" These simple questions out of curiosity have always thrown me off, and I had to contemplate my identity. I don't remember how I answered on the spot, but I always thought, “I don't know.”

Comment: I don't see any problem with the quotation marks. Online grammar checkers aren't infallible.

Comment: I found the issue in premium Grammarly alone. So much for premium.

Comment: A reasonable question that is amenable to a reasonable answer. I have compensated for the unexplained and unhelpful downvote that someone gave.

Comment: Is this really on-topic here? The top answer below needed a Grammarly subscription to answer. Is that an expectation on this site? The lack of an existing [grammarly] tag makes me think no.

Comment: Grammarly is not a very useful source for English grammar. And in any case this is about punctuation, not English.

Answer (score 17):

The issue appears to be that you have used both "straight" and “curly” quotes.

[image: Grammarly screenshot: "Inconsistent punctuation. You used two different styles of apostrophes or quotation marks in your document. Both styles are acceptable, but it's best to be consistent."]

Changing the curly ones to straight makes the problem go away.